# Is there any way to add 2 indicators with different overlay?

Tags: pine-script, overlay, pine-script-v5, trading

Is there any way to add 2 indicators with different overlay. Eg: in 1 pine script, I have EMA with `overlay=true` and RSI with `overlay=false` ?

```
indicator(title="RSI Indicator", overlay=false)
#code for RSI indicator

indicator(title="EMA Indicator", overlay=true)
#code for EMA indicator
```

Comment: No, it's not a function aviable in TradingView